# Using k-nearest neighbor (k-NN) to pair similar observations from two populations

Tags: r, k-nearest-neighbour

I am working with two datasets in R. Each is a sample from populations of interest. Dataset A contains 352 observations. Dataset B contains 8,000 observations. My objective is to find observations from dataset B that resemble observations from dataset A, determined by a number of specified socioeconomic attributes (i.e., find the nearest neighbors of A in B). The result will be a new, third dataset containing observations from both populations (n=704).

The objective is conceptually rather simple, I think, but I'm unclear from the help documentation for ?knn and extant tutorials how to technically execute this plan. The closest solution I've come across after searching is [this Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276866/how-to-use-nearest-neighbor-to-find-similar-population-based-on-list-of-features), but it is for SAS; thus, the supposed answer is difficult for me to translate into R.

Any help or suggestions would be most welcome.